# NetBeans - CleanUp like in eclipse option/addon

Tags: java, netbeans, formatting, code-cleanup

There is any options or plugins/addons for NetBeans to use CleanUp options? That was very useful option.

I don't mean only formatting code and fix imports but all that options like adding "final" to every possible (local or not) variable/field (it's easier to read code).

Answer (score 0):

It has many shortcut keys for that. This are some of them: [Highlights of NetBeans IDE 7.0 Keyboard Shortcuts & Code Templates](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf)

Comment: I don't see any options that I was looking for

Comment: You can also check here: [Userguide shortcuts](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts.pdf) . But my results were very easy to find, you should try much harder before asking something or be more specific.

Comment: Still no that options, "options like adding "final" to every possible (local or not) variable/field". I don't see any options for that in NetBeans